# PHP and ElasticSearch 6.7 - Doubles Being Parsed As Strings

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a ElasticSearch 6.7 index with a mapping that resembles:

```
    {
      "mapping": {
        "doc": {
          "properties": {
            "brand": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "time_count": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "total_cost": {
               "type": "double"
            },
            ...
         }
      }
```

When I use the official PHP and [ElasticSearch library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) to index some documents, the indexing is successful but all of my double/integer datapoints are parsed as strings, and I am unable to use any numeric aggregations or search terms.

I have tried forcing the type in PHP when going to index, but that does not fix the issue.

```
$index = [
   'brand' => (string) $brand,
   'time_count' => (double) $t->rate_bill_min,
   'total_cost' => (double) $t->vendor_bill_min
   ...
];
$up = [
  'body' => $payload,
  'index' => 'termination_metrics',
];

$r = $client->index($up);
```

What must I do in order to preserve the double/integer status of my data when it is indexed?

Comment: Are they actually stored in Elasticsearch as strings, or are they simply being `returned` as strings? Many DB drivers will return floating points as string values so as to avoid floating point error. You also should not be storing money as floats _anywhere_ for the same reason. In Elasticsearch there's [`scaled_float`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html) which is really just an integer and a divisor, equivalent to a `DECIMAL` type in most RDBMSes.

Comment: @Sammitch Kibana is listing them as strings. If the mapping is true, I guess that would indicate that they are being stored that way. Is that valid thinking?